# Three stage Sudoku puzzle generator

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, sudoku

This was my first time attempting a project like this, so I figured it would improve readability, and would also just be nice If I allowed each stage to be visualized.

Also, this only generates them, I haven't done any solving code, so it can't know if a puzzle has multiple solutions. I didn't forget, I just want to perfect this part first.

First up is the `Main.java` class. it contains the vast majority of my code, and is divided up into several methods whose purposes should be pretty obvious. also, I'd like to mention that while I don't have it implemented here, my code could scale up puzzles other sizes as well.

```
package com.kestrel.sudoku.generate;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main4
{
    public static int[] seed = new int[81];
    public static int[] cells = new int[81];
    public static int[] finalPuzzle = new int[81];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        genSeed();
        genSudoku();
        genResult();

        printSeed();
        System.out.println();
        printSudoku();
        System.out.println();
        printResult();

    }

    public static boolean genSudoku()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if(cells[9 * y + x] == 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                    {
                        int n = r.nextInt(9) + 1;

                        if(isSafe(x, y, n))
                        {
                            cells[9 * y + x] = n;

                            if(genSudoku())
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cells[9 * y + x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(cells[9 * y + i] == n)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(cells[9 * i + x] == n)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int a = 0 ; a < 3; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0 ; b < 3; b++)
            {

                if (cells[9 * (y - y % 3) + (x - x % 3) + (9 * a + b)] == n)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void fill(int[] a, int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            cells[i] = num;
        }
    }

    public static void genSeed()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            int n = r.nextInt(81);
            if(seed[n] == 1 || seed[80 - n] == 1 )
            {
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                seed[n] = 1;
                seed[80 - n] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void genResult()
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) 
         { 
             for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
             {
                 if(seed[9 * y + x] == 1)
                 {
                     finalPuzzle[9 * y + x] = cells[9 * y + x];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     finalPuzzle[9 * y + x] = 0;
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    public static void printSeed()
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) 
         { 
             for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
             {
                 System.out.print(seed[9 * y + x] + " ");
                 if(x % 3 == 2 && x < 8)
                 {
                     System.out.print("| ");
                 }
             }
             System.out.println();
             if(y % 3 == 2 && y < 8)
             {
                 System.out.println("---------------------");
             }
         } 
    }

    public static void printSudoku() 
    { 
         for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) 
         { 
             for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
             {
                 System.out.print(cells[9 * y + x] + " ");
                 if(x % 3 == 2 && x < 8)
                 {
                     System.out.print("| ");
                 }
             }
             System.out.println();
             if(y % 3 == 2 && y < 8)
             {
                 System.out.println("---------------------");
             }
         } 
    }

    public static void printResult() 
    { 
         for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) 
         { 
             for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
             {
                 if(seed[9 * y + x] == 1)
                 {
                     System.out.print(finalPuzzle[9 * y + x] + " ");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.print("  ");
                 }

                 if(x % 3 == 2 && x < 8)
                 {
                     System.out.print("| ");
                 }
             }
             System.out.println();
             if(y % 3 == 2 && y < 8)
             {
                 System.out.println("---------------------");
             }
         } 
    }
}
```

One part that I'm really not happy with is that I couldn't figure out any solution other than a recursive function for generating the full Sudoku. I'm guess It might just be because I'm still semi-new to programming, but It just looks really ugly. at one point, I thought I had a solution, a double `for` loop where one would increment, and the other would decrement, and they shared a variable, but I just couldn't get it to work. I guess the other thing I should mention is the lack of 2d arrays in my code. I don't like them either. I'd rather just do the math. I don't know if it's faster, (its probably not) but I think that's just kinda my coding style at this point. plus, I didn't have to iterate over every single cell this way. only the ones I wanted to. I think that should be it. Looking at it now... I think I could probably get rid of some duplicate code in the `isSafe()` and `printX()` functions. so... how did I do?

Comment: What is the purpose of the class `Cell`? It is never used in the main program?

Comment: ... you are correct. One of the previous versions used it, and I guess I got confused. My project basically looks like a whole bunch of main#.java files, and then whatever else they use, with pretty much zero  indication of what uses what. I'll fix that.

Comment: `genSudoku()` is actually also a puzzle solving function, in addition to being a puzzle generating function.  So you can use that to verify that the final puzzle has a solution (although there may be more than 1 solution).   However it is quite inefficient and I suggest looking at other sudoku solvers for inspiration (some are on this site even).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generating one Sudoku, you should only create a single random number generator. It should be configurable so that you can pass a predictable random number generator during tests. Like this:

```
public class SudokuGenerator {

    private final Random rnd;

    public SudokuGenerator(Random rnd) {
        this.rnd = rnd;
    }

    public Sudoku generate() {
        …
    }
}
```

The current `genSolve` code looks frightening and inefficient. Having a 3-times nested `for` loops combined with 3 intermingled `if` statements and calling this method recursively sounds like a bad design. There must be something simpler. I don't know what, but it must exist.

A fairly advanced Sudoku generator is available [as part of Simon Tatham's Puzzle Collection](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/puzzles.git;a=blob;f=solo.c). The code is written in C but has lots of explaining comments, so you should be able to get some ideas.

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty much a nightmare to get working. Trust me, if I could have gotten that damn for-loop-thing to work, I 100% would have used it instead. The issue was that it just didn't "remember" stuff like the resursive one did. I tried to implement it with a stack, but no dice.

Answer (score 3):

1. The `fill` method is never used.
2. State should not be `public static`. By passing the relevant data to the relevant methods, you can make a lot more sense of your code, and allow more reusability of methods.
3. None of your methods save `main` need be `public`.
4. Choosing a data structure is not a matter of coding style! If you are going to use a 1D array to represent a grid, a rather unintuitive choice, it better help you write elegant code. There are a few places were we can use this 1D structure to our advantage: looping over `n` instead of `x, y` in `genSodoku` and `genResult` for instance.
5. `genSoduku` is implemented very inefficiently. Instead of looping to find the next empty value, just pass it to the recursive call.
6. In the same method, you need to use a random permutation instead of a random generator. `Random.nextInt` samples "with replacement"; thus some numbers might not be considered. I used `Collections.shuffle` to do same "without replacement" instead.
7. `genSeed` is ill-documented. Explain why you are selecting numbers likes this.
8. In `genResult` multiply `cells[n]` and `seed[n]` to get the same result.
9. Consolidate printing into a single `printBoard` method that take a 9-by-9 table.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] seed = genSeed();
        int[] cells = genSudoku();
        int[] finalPuzzle = genResult(seed, cells);

        printBoard(seed);
        printBoard(cells);
        printBoard(finalPuzzle);
    }

    private static int[] genSudoku() {
        int[] cells = new int[81];
        genHelper(cells, 0);
        return cells;
    }

    private static List<Integer> getPermutation() {
        List<Integer> choices = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,9)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(choices);
        return choices;
    }

    private static boolean genHelper(int[] cells, int n) {
        if (n == 81) {
            return true;
        }

        List<Integer> choices = getPermutation();
        for (int k : choices) {
            if(isSafe(cells, n, k)) {
                cells[n] = k;
                if(genHelper(cells, n + 1)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        cells[n] = 0;
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isSafe(int[] cells, int n, int k) {
        int y = n / 9, x = n % 9;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(cells[9 * y + i] == k || cells[9 * i + x] == k) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int a = 0 ; a < 3; a++) {
            for (int b = 0 ; b < 3; b++) {
                if (cells[9 * (y - y % 3) + (x - x % 3) + (9 * a + b)] == k) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static int[] genSeed() {
        int[] seed = new int[81];
        Random r = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int n = r.nextInt(81);
            if(seed[n] == 1 || seed[80 - n] == 1 ) {
                i--;
            } else {
                seed[n] = 1;
                seed[80 - n] = 1;
            }
        }
        return seed;
    }

    private static int[] genResult(int[] seed, int[] cells) {
        int[] finalPuzzle = new int[81];
        for(int n = 0; n < 81; n++) {
            finalPuzzle[n] = seed[n] * cells[n];
        }
        return finalPuzzle;
    }

    private static void printBoard(int[] board) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) { 
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                System.out.print(board[9 * y + x] + " ");
                if(x % 3 == 2 && x < 8) {
                    System.out.print("| ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            if(y % 3 == 2 && y < 8) {
                System.out.println("---------------------");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```